# How to set offset for LockFileEx like LockFile

Tags: winapi

I need to lock a file for read and write operation and preferably I would like to lock only a region. As I need to use LockFileEx instead of LockFile I don't understand how to specify a lock region because there's only a `nNumberOfBytesToLock` parameter and no `dwFileOffsetLow` like with LockFile.

Does it allow only to lock from the beginning ?

Thanks

Comment: *A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure that the function uses with the locking request. This structure, which is required, **contains the file offset of the beginning of the lock range.**

Comment: The use of the last argument is not optional like it normally is, set its Offset/High member to specify the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file offset is part of the `lpOverlapped` parameter.